# Split "Trash" directories on KDE5

Tags: kde, trash, kde5

In KDE4 (Kubuntu 14.04) there was a trash directory per file system (on /home it was somewhere under ~, on other filesystems it was (from memory) a /.trash/{id}/. The benefit was that trashing files was quick since they were just moved to that directory.

In KDE5 (Kubuntu 16.04) I only have one trash directory in /home, and deleting things on the second disk is slow (and induces wear in the SSD). Is there a way to configure trash to work as in KDE4?

Comment: Let me get this straight - on a plain filesystem being used for data, for example, KDE now moves the trashed files to ANOTHER filesystem? If I've undestood you correctly, that is incredibly bad design. I presume this is from a gui filebrowser. Have you tried trash-cli? You could write a script to use it and make it a right click option on most gui filebrowsers. Thunar & Spacefm both make that sort of thing easy. I started using it because the Thunar devs got so schiz about the "right" way to trash files, I finally decided to roll my own. Now I've switched to Spacefm but I still use trash-cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Specifications and Standards**

The KDE (*1) is using Freedesktop specifications: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/ . In this case - Desktop Trash Can Specification: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/

By the 'Trash directories' (short):

- A system can have one or more trash directories.
- An administrator can create an $topdir/.Trash directory.
  If an $topdir/.Trash directory is absent, an $topdir/.Trash-$uid directory is to be used as the user's trash directory for this device/partition. $uid is the user's numeric identifier.
- When trashing a file, if this directory does not exist for the current user, the implementation MUST immediately create it, without any warnings or delays for the user.
- If both (1) and (2) fail (that is, no $topdir/.Trash directory exists, and an attempt to create $topdir/.Trash-$uid fails), the implementation MUST either trash the file into the user's “home trash” or refuse to trash it.

At here, with the Dolphin file manager, 'trashing' the 'TrashTest.txt' file:

[image]

The /.Trash-$uid is created.

Does your user and the KDE session have the right to create the needed /.Trash-$uid ?

***1)** There is no KDE5. There are KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5), Plasma 5 and the KDE Applications. The KF5 and the plasma version can be looked from the KInfocenter: https://www.kde.org/applications/system/kinfocenter/ . The KDE Applications version can be looked from the application help page.

Comment: Good to know. However after creating /disk2/.Trash (with flags rwxrwxrwx) and /disk2/.Trash-1000 (and giving me ownership) neither is used when I delete files in Dolphin (files still end up in `~/.local/share/Trash/files/)`. `trashbin` also still considers one single disk when configuring the percentage reserved for trash.

Comment: Eventually got it to work. It really wants the `$topdir/.Trash` directory to have the sticky bit. Couldn't find a way to make the other variant (`$topdir/.Trash-$uid`) work, though.