# Recycle Bin in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, trash

good to everyone. Happy New Year.

I have a few months in the linux world and Xubuntu 20.04 and later Xubuntu 20.04.1 are my default operating systems on my Acer mini laptop.

I have another PC to which I want to install Kubuntu 20.04.1, since it has the power and the KDE graphical environment is beautiful. But I have a downside. I tried it some time ago and everything worked fine, but I don't like how it manages the trash can. I explain.

I have a partition «Data» (NTFS because I have dual boot and "defaults, permissions") in which I keep all my files. In Xubuntu / Ubuntu it creates a folder ".Trash-1000" or ".Trash-1001", depending on the users I have on my system. But in Kubuntu all the deleted files were moved to the "/home/.local/share/Trash/" folder and I don't want that to happen because it slows down the file deletion a bit, at the same time that it fills the partition where I have installed the system.

I read a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/934932/split-trash-directories-on-kde5) where it said that possibly my user and KDE do not have permission to create the $ topdir / .Trash- $ uid directory. But I don't know how to give it permissions, since distros like Ubuntu / Xubuntu / Linux Mint deleted files from other disks without problems.

I translated it with google translate, sorry for the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As an Administrator you can create the $topdir/.Trash directory which will be used. See the specifications [here.](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) Pay close attention to the part where it indicates that "The sticky bit must be set if the filesystem supports it. (This may actually be the root cause of your problem).
Here's an excerpt from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits#h8-the-sticky-bit

> The sticky bit works in a different way: while it has no effect on
> files, when used on a directory, all the files in said directory will
> be modifiable only by their owners. A typical case in which it is
> used, involves the /tmp directory. Typically this directory is
> writable by all users on the system, so to make impossible for one
> user to delete the files of another one, the sticky bit is set:
>
> $ ls -ld /tmp drwxrwxrwt. 14 root root 300 Nov  1 16:48 /tmp
>
> In this case the owner, the group, and all other users, have full
> permissions on the directory (read, write and execute). The sticky bit
> is identifiable by a t which is reported where normally the executable
> x bit is shown, in the "other" section. Again, a lowercase t implies
> that the executable bit is also present, otherwise you would see a
> capital T

Sources:
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-special-permissions-the-setuid-setgid-and-sticky-bits#h8-the-sticky-bit